# Left join with calculated column and different schemas?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, hql, calculated-columns

I would like to perform a left join on the following tables:

```
Vehicles.boats,
vehicle_details.colors
```

With columns

```
 vehicles.boats.yacht
 color_id
```

where `color_id` is computed from `vehicle_details.colors` in a calculation that involves

```
vehicle_details.colors.sequence
 and 
vehicle_details.colors.name
```

I assume the following would serve as my skeleton, but I am unsure of where to put the calculations that define `color_id`:

```
SELECT vehicles.boats.yacht, vehicle_details.colors.sequence
FROM vehicles.boats
LEFT JOIN vehicle_details.colors 
ON vehicle.boats.colorIdentifier = color_id;
```

Would it be something like the following, where the calculation is used in the `ON` portion?

```
SELECT vehicles.boats.yacht, vehicle_details.colors.sequence
FROM vehicles.boats
LEFT JOIN vehicle_details.colors 
ON vehicle.boats.colorIdentifier = *calculations* AS color_id;
```

Comment: I'm just lost.  What tables have which columns?  What mysterious calculation are you making?  And what is your actual question?  If you are asking if you can do calculations in the `on` clause, the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

In that format you need to do the calculation twice, once for the join condition, once for the display.

```
SELECT vehicles.boats.yacht, vehicle_details.colors.sequence,*calculations* AS color_id;
FROM vehicles.boats
LEFT JOIN vehicle_details.colors 
ON vehicles.boats.colorIdentifier = *calculations*;
```

You could use a subquery and do it once, something like:

```
SELECT vehicles.boats.yacht, vehicle_details.colors.sequence, color_id;
FROM vehicles.boats
LEFT JOIN ( Select vehicle_details.colors, *calculations* as colour_id from vehicle_details) as Details_subquery
ON vehicles.boats.colorIdentifier = colour_id ;
```